# Countable additivity of a finitely additive set function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm new to measure theory and trying to solve this problem from Ash's book.

Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative, finitely additive set function on a field $\it{F}$. If $A_1, A_2,... $ are disjoint sets in $\it{F}$, and $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty } A_n \in \it{F} $ then show that,

$$ \mu( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty } A_n) \geq \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu( A_i ) $$

My thoughts are: The above inequality is an equality $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $. But I cannot find the jump from finite additivity to countable additivity. Can someone please give me hints on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \mu( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty } A_n) \geq  \mu( \cup_{n=1}^{N } A_n) = \Sigma_{n=1}^{N} \mu( A_i ) $$ for each $N$. Now take limit as $N \to \infty$.

The first inequlaity follows from the fact that $A \subset B, A,B \in F$ implies $\mu(A) \leq \mu (B)$.